# SortRole in QSortFilterProxyModel is not set

Tags: qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

I create a `qtableview` with a custom model and a custom sortfilterproxymodel

```
IssueTableModel *issueModel = new IssueTableModel(this->_repository->getIssueList());
IssueTableSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new IssueTableSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxyModel->setSourceModel(issueModel);
this->_ui->issuesTable->setModel(proxyModel);
```

and in the sortfilterproxymodel constructor:

```
IssueTableSortFilterProxyModel::IssueTableSortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent) : QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
    this->setSortRole(Qt::UserRole);
    this->setFilterRole(Qt::UserRole);
}
```

with a custom `lessThan` method in the proxymodel. but when the data is retrieved via the model `data` method, only

- Qt::DisplayRole
- Qt::DecorationRole
- Qt::FontRole
- Qt::TextAlignmentRole
- Qt::BackgroundRole
- Qt::ForegroundRole
- Qt::CheckStateRole
- Qt::SizeHintRole

are called, but not Qt::UserRole which I need to output the correct sorting data for the model item:

```
QVariant IssueTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    switch (role) {
        case Qt::DecorationRole:
            // Display icons
            switch (index.column()) {
                [...]
            }
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            // Display text data
            switch (index.column()) {
                [...]
            }
        case Qt::UserRole:
            qDebug() << "USER ROLE!!!!";
            // Return data for sorting/filtering
            switch (index.column()) {
                [...]
            }
        default:
            return QVariant();
    }
}
```

So the question is: Why does the `data` method of the model never get called with Qt::UserRole when sorting the proxymodel?

**Solution:**

I got the data in the `lessThan` method via:

```
bool IssueTableSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left, const QModelIndex &right) const
{
    QVariant leftData = sourceModel()->data(left);
    QVariant rightData = sourceModel()->data(right);

    switch (leftData.type()) {
        case QVariant::Int:
            return leftData.toInt() < rightData.toInt();
        case QVariant::String:
            return leftData.toString() < rightData.toString();
        case QVariant::DateTime:
            return leftData.toDateTime() < rightData.toDateTime();
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

but did not set the second parameter of the `data` method which specifies the role...

```
QVariant leftData = sourceModel()->data(left, Qt::UserRole);
```

Comment: Have you actually set a filter on your model or enabled sorting?  Your user role will not be queried unless you do.

Comment: What do you mean by "set a filter"? I enabled sorting, i currently have 6 columns in my table, 4 are QStrings which get sorted because they are returned by the Qt::DisplayRole. 2 columns are QIcons which are returned by Qt::DisplayRole and they should get sorted by a custom integer which should be returned in the Qt::UserRole.

Comment: Can you post your code for `lessThan`?  If you have reimplemented it then setSortRole will have no effect unless you use it yourself.

Comment: Ahh that was the reason:( if you could post this answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reimplement `lessThan` then you need to perform the sorting yourself.  setSortRole only affects the default `lessThan` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should either:

call

```
void QSortFilterProxyModel::sort ( int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder ) [virtual]
```

setsorting in your view (and click columns)

```
setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Set dynamic filtering

```
void QSortFilterProxyModel::setDynamicSortFilter ( bool enable )
```

Edit:

Note that, in docs. They say in [example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details):

> At this point, neither sorting nor filtering is enabled; the original
>   data is displayed in the view. Any changes made through the
>   QSortFilterProxyModel are applied to the original model.

You MUST fire the filtering/sorting